# programme -> program. Acceptable?

Tags: discussion, edits

I'm not sure what language(spoken) it is, but there seem to be a lot of questions that use the word `programme` instead of `program`

Is it acceptable to change this to `program` or am I just being American?

Comment: Why are those mutually exclusive?

Comment: it annoys me cause it isn't consistent...

Comment: Oh snap, what happens when we get to colours? Centre?

Comment: @mmyers @MPel color and colours and all those kinda things are fine with me. programme and program less so because it is central to the main theme of stackoverflow. Does that mean we should allow tags like (bogus of course) `[script-programme]` and `[script-program]` to coexist just because of locale differences?

Comment: @earlz: That isn't a locale difference - because it would be script-program everywhere. It's only *non*-computer programmes which have the extra "me". It's a bit like "compact disc" but "hard disk".

Comment: @MPelletier: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24878/retag-request-colors-color-on-so/45429#45429

Comment: Personally it annoys me that Americans forget that the other 98% of the world is not American and take it upon themselves to bastardise (notice the spelling!) the Queen's English. You will never take colour, centre, licence, bonnet, boot, chips, jam, biscuit, tap and all the rest from me!!! W00t!

Comment: `Programme` is a nice word and BTW a plural form.

Comment: Just retagged 3 [initialisation] to [initialization]. I died a little inside...

Comment: @slugster it's spelled biskit. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're spellchecking against [Correct English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_English), then programme is fine for talking about TV, radio and management topics.

Here's a prime example:

> I'm creating a TV Guide which lists **programmes** coming up (and on some listings, previous airings from the past), with all data stored in a database. [...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031451/tv-guide-written-in-php-problems-with-datetime-and-database-functions)

For the most part, program, is the chosen spelling in computing.

But yes, blanket changing of the word programme to program, without care or read into context,  would be considered overly American since their minds only know one version of that particular word. (And many others like practise/practice.)

Comment: practise isn't a word. firefox says so. ;)

Comment: @earlz: You're likely using an American English dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of tag blacklist or auto-changing tags to more consistent ones, we should have auto-changing of strange foreign spellings to the correct one.

It's just a [simple matter of programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_matter_of_programming).

Comment: However each auto-retag should be very. carefully. considered. Program and programme are different things, wheras color and (the correct) colour are the same (But I'm more than happy to have colour->color, because consistency is better than correctness in such minor matters)

Answer (score 1):

*Program* is regarded as acceptable in British English to refer to a computer program, but in other uses the word is *Programme*.

I would regard a *computer programme* as pedantic.

Answer (score 0):

*Programme* is British English. I once spoke to a British contractor at the European Space Agency's technical centre ([ESTEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Space_Research_and_Technology_Centre)) in the Netherlands who was very insistent on using programme (about software), but I think most Britons are fine with *program*.

Answer (score 0):

**Ye Olde Stacke OverFlowe.com**

Joel has talked about having foreign language stack overflows.  Maybe we can pilot with Great Britain!